# Convert table into list

Tags: google-sheets, list, pivot-table

I need to convert a table into a list so it can be used as a database

[image]

Into this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See [Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C2vxL3XyWAAKXxjSjkX-xWfps5hQwzPX2JrU6F6_Ooo/edit#gid=794529788) cell **I2**

Formula consists of 4 parts for each column.

```
ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",REPT(A2:A&",", COUNTA($C$1:$G$1))), ","))), 
ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",REPT(B2:B&",", COUNTA($C$1:$G$1))), ","))),
```

These parts of formula repeat values from columns **A** and **B** N times, where N is number of columns with data in your initial table (5 in example), thus you can adjust it to table size changing this part COUNTA($C$1:$G$1).

```
ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(JOIN(",",$C$1:$G$1&","),COUNTA(A2:A)),",")))
```

this formula repeats headers of initial table N times, where N is number of rows in your data. Also can be adjusted for different tables by changing $C$1:$G$1 - headers range.

```
ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(C2:G&","),",")))
```

Last part transforms values from table into single column. Also can be adjusted for different tables by changing C2:G.